# inserting in a sorted linked list in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, comparator

I need to insert some objects contained in a Node class into a LinkedList class in a sorted over. The Node class looks like:

```
public class Node {
    private Card val;
    private Node next;
    public Node(Card v) {
        val = v;
        next = null;
}
```

where card implements the Comparator interface. I'm trying to write a function to insert these cards in sorted order (low to high) by card value in a LinkedList class (not the java.util.LinkedList class but a linked-list class I'm writing). Does anybody know how I could do this? Also it can't be a doubly-linked list.

Comment: Are you asking about what conceptual steps it takes to sort these cards, or how to implement the steps in Java code? In other words, are you confused about the algorithm or the implementation? (Or both?) More detail on what you've tried and where you've gotten stuck would be helpful.

Comment: I'm asking for the implementation. Everything I've been trying I'm running into a lot of NPEs.

Comment: In that case, it might be helpful for you to post what you've tried. Perhaps you're on the right track, and people can point out your specific mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking is something like what I came up below (note I didn't compile, but it should give you an idea and hopefully helps you)

```
public class Node {
    private Card val;
    private Node next;

    public Node(Card v) {
        val = v;
        next = null;
    }
    public Card getVal() { return val; }
    oublic void setVal(Card v) { val = v; }
    public Node getNext() { return next; }
    public void setNext(Node n) { next = n; }
}

public class MyLinkList {
    private Node head = null;

    public void addNode(Card v) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(v);
        } else {
            Node  last = null;
            for (Node node = head; node != null && node.getVal().compareTo(v) < 0 ; ) {
                last = node;
                node = node.next;
            }

            Node newNode = new Node(v);
            last.setNext(newNode);
            newNode.setNext(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would remove the Node#setVal method, it isn't used and may just corrupt the ordering if you use it...

Comment: I added that at the last minute too, thinking just like you.  Last minute, I just threw it in there.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried with this code.. its bit messy but can help you..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Card[] cards = { new Card(10), new Card(5), new Card(34), new Card(2)};
  Node node = new Node(new Card(1));
  Node firstNode = node;
  Node tran = firstNode;
  for (Card c : cards) {
   Node newNode = new Node(c);
   int a=0;
   do {
    if(a==1) {
     tran = tran.getNode();
    }
    if ((tran.getCard().compareTo(c) == -1)) {
     if (tran.getNode() == null) {
      tran.setNode(newNode);
      firstNode = node;
      break;
     } else if (tran.getNode() != null && ran.getNode().getCard().compareTo(c) == +1) {
      newNode.setNode(tran.getNode());
      node.setNode(newNode);
      firstNode = node;
      break;
     }
    } else if ((tran.getCard().compareTo(c) == +1)) {
     newNode.setNode(tran.getNode());
     firstNode = newNode;
     break;
    } else  if(tran.getCard().compareTo(c) == 0){
     newNode.setNode(tran.getNode());
     firstNode = newNode;
     break;
    }
    a=1;
   } while (tran.getNode() != null);
   tran = firstNode;
  }
  Node traversalNode = firstNode;
  while (traversalNode.getNode() != null) {
   System.out.println(traversalNode.getCard());
   traversalNode = traversalNode.getNode();
  }
 }
```